# How to show first data in table view while fetch data from api

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have one collection view and it have some 5 cells. Which are I am fetching from api to show the cells data in collection view. And when user click any cell, that approprate data will display in below table view.

Now, every thing works fine. But when I load first time my view. No data are displaying in my table view... What I mean is? By default first data of collection view cell have to show in tableview. But I am not getting or not able to display.

If I click any cell only, I can see the data in my table view. But what I need is - By default first cell of collection view have to display in table view when ever i open that screen

How to do that?

**Here is my code:**

```
@IBOutlet var BTCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet var DLTableView: UITableView!

    var BTdata = [BTData]()

    var Dealsdata = [DealsData]()
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 // nib for custom cell (table view)
        let nib = UINib(nibName:"DealsListTableCell", bundle: nil)
        DLTableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DealCell")

        ListBusinessTypes()
}
    // Values from Api for Business Types
    func ListBusinessTypes()
    {
        let token = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("access_token") as! String

        let headers = ["x-access-token": token]

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "httpsome url")!,
                                          cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print(error)

                let ErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Problem with internet connectivity or server, please try after some time", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                // add an action (button)
                ErrorAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                // show the alert
                self.presentViewController(ErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                {
                    let success = json["success"] as? Int

                    if(success == 1)
                    {
                        if let typeValues = json["data"] as? [NSDictionary]
                        {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                                for item in typeValues
                                {
                                    self.BTdata.append(BTData(json:item))

                                    self.BTCollectionView.reloadData()
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let message = json["message"] as? String

                        print(message)

                        let ServerAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                        // add an action (button)
                        ServerAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                        // show the alert
                        self.presentViewController(ServerAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
    }

// Mark : Collection View Delegate and Datasource(Business Type)
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return BTdata.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell: DDLCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("HCollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DDLCollectionCell
        cell.BTName.text = BTdata[indexPath.row].BTNames
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        ListDeals(BTdata[indexPath.row].BTIds!)
    }


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    // number of rows
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return Dealsdata.count
    }

    // calling each cell based on tap and users ( premium / non premium )
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let tabcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DealCell") as! DealsListTableCell

        tabcell.DealName.text = Dealsdata[indexPath.row].DealNames

        if let imgURL = NSURL(string: Dealsdata[indexPath.row].DealImageUrls!)
        {
            let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)

            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

            let Imgtask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
            {
                (data, response, error) -> Void in

                if (error == nil && data != nil)
                {
                    func display_image()
                    {
                        tabcell.DealImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    }
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), display_image)
                }
            }
            Imgtask.resume()
        }
        else
        {
            tabcell.DealImage.image = UIImage(named: "FBLogo")
        }

        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSxxx"

        let date = formatter.dateFromString(Dealsdata[indexPath.row].DealExpiry!)

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
        let FormattedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)

        tabcell.RegPriceLabel.text = String(Dealsdata[indexPath.row].DealRegularPrice!)

        tabcell.SalePriceLabel.text = String(Dealsdata[indexPath.row].DealSalePrice!)

        tabcell.DealExpiryDate.text = "Expiries on : "+FormattedDate

        let BArrayValue:NSDictionary = Dealsdata[indexPath.row].DealBusinessDetails!

        let BName = BArrayValue.valueForKey("business_name") as! String

        let BImage = BArrayValue.valueForKey("images") as! NSArray

        let BMainImage = BImage[0] as! NSDictionary

        let FinalImage = BMainImage.valueForKey("url") as! String

        if let imgURL2 = NSURL(string: FinalImage)
        {
            let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL2)

            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

            let Imgtask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
            {
                (data, response, error) -> Void in

                if (error == nil && data != nil)
                {
                    func display_image()
                    {
                        tabcell.DealBusinessImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    }
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), display_image)
                }
            }
            Imgtask.resume()
        }
        else
        {
            tabcell.DealBusinessImage.image = UIImage(named: "FBLogo")
        }


        let BLatLng = Dealsdata[indexPath.row].DealCoordinates

        let UserLocation = CLLocation(latitude: NewCurrentLatitude, longitude: NewCurrentLongitude)

        let BusinessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: BLatLng![0] as! Double, longitude: BLatLng![1] as! Double)

        let distance = UserLocation.distanceFromLocation(BusinessLocation) / 1000

        tabcell.DealBusinessNameWithDistance.text = BName+" - "+String(format: "%.1f",distance)+" Km"

        return tabcell
    }
```

Please help me out. Thanks!

Does i need to change any thing in below line:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        ListDeals(BTdata[indexPath.row].BTIds!)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `ListDeals(BTdata[0].BTIds!)` after you loaded the data from your API.

```
...

if let typeValues = json["data"] as? [NSDictionary]
                    {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                            for item in typeValues
                            {
                                self.BTdata.append(BTData(json:item))

                                self.BTCollectionView.reloadData()
                            }
                            ListDeals(BTdata[0].BTIds!)
                        })
                    }

...
```

Comment: Yes, when i load my screen first data is showing.But now new problem occur.That is - There is 5 cell.Only first two cell having data.other cells are dont have data.But when i press my 3rd cell.My second cell data are still there in table view..This problem is for my 3,4, 5 th cells too,